# C++: String formatting

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdstring

This is my input string: Muhammad Ali 65445519 76 butterfly123

This is my desired output: Muhammad Ali xxx-xx-xxx 76 xxxxxxxxx

Note: Other than the social security number(65445519) everything can vary in length i.e. Name, UserID(76) and passoword(butterfly123).

example:

Kobe Bryant 34567890 548 56mamba

I've given it a try BUT I have a fixed User ID of length 2. Can anyone come up with a solution in which the User ID can also vary? or a whole new different approach? I don't want to use string streams, in which you take the input one by one and then process the string respectively. However an effective and short string stream solution will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
string s;
int j;
getline(cin,s);
for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
{
    if(s.at(i)=='0' || s.at(i)=='1' || s.at(i)=='2'
        || s.at(i)=='3' || s.at(i)=='4' || s.at(i)=='5'
        || s.at(i)=='6' || s.at(i)=='7' || s.at(i)=='8'
        || s.at(i)=='9')
    {
        s.replace(i,8,"xxxxxxxx");
        s.insert(i+3,"-");
        s.insert(i+6,"-");
        j=i+14;
        break;
    }
}
for(j;j<s.length();j++)
{
    s.replace(j,1,"x");
}
cout<<s<<endl;
```

Comment: Why not include `cctype` and use `isdigit((unsigned char)s.at(i))` instead of the long condition in `if`?

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks man, used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have to use `getline(cin,s);`, you can read the data into separate variables:

```
std::string name, surname, password;
unsigned long long security, ID;

std::cin >> name >> surname >> security >> ID >> password;

std::string processed_security, processed_pwd(password.size(), 'x');

while (security) processed_security += "x", security /= 10;

std::cout << name << surname << processed_security << ID << processed_pwd << std::endl;
```

Some notes on this code:

1. You can use a smaller unsigned integer datatype for ID (e.g. `unsigned int`)
2. `security` should be held in a datatype that can hold very large numbers, e.g. `unsigned long long`
3. [Docs for the `std::string` constructors used](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

Comment: Thanks this probably is the only way to do it, other ways you might incur an error.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a new class with name,ID, password...  and just override the ">>" operator?

and to creat the  "xxxxxxxxxx" use the string constructor :

```
string word(oldword.size(), 'x');
```

oldword.size() is how long the word is , and 'x' is the character that will fill the whole string

Comment: @Mohsin you can make a structure, but that is like a class :D
i like to make classes because you can override their operators for everything and then  you can use functions from the Standard Template Library on them like they are a basic type

Comment: @MiloRadosavljevic the above answer is feasible, I'm solving a question in it, it states not to use classes but anyways applied all the other suggestions. Thanks

Comment: @Mohsin Instead of a lot of "if"s you can use compare funciton http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should try a different approach.

Consider the following input

```
Sam123456789 FarkenParker 221778833 46 foobar
```

Your approach will end up replacing "123456789" with X-s, which is clearly wrong.

The correct approach:

1) Split the single string into whitespace-delimited words. Use `std::array<std::string, 4>`, or `std::vector<std::string>`, whatever works for you.

2) Simply replace the 2nd and the 5th word accordingly.

3) Then combine everything back, into a single string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. If you come up with anything else do let me know, don't want to use arrays, vectors or classes.